# mongodb query on array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi I have the following database em mongodb and I need a query to get a single object of the array, like the object card with the number 18, all the queries I did returned the entire array and not only the object I want, how I can do it?

```
{"Cards":
              [
                        {"Card":{"_id":{"$oid":"5a46626e150ed3f847f01bac"},"Number":1,"Pag":1}},
                        {"Card":{"_id":{"$oid":"5a466d96150ed3f847f01bad"},"Number":18,"Pag":6}},
                        {"Card":{"_id":{"$oid":"5a466de6150ed3f847f01bae"},"Number":35,"Pag":8}}
              ]
        }
```

Comment: Do you have any examples of queries that you've tried?

Comment: I tryied `db.teste.find({"Cards.Card.Number":18}).pretty()` and it returned the entire array

Comment: also tryed `db.teste.find({"Cards.Card.Number":18},{_id:0, "Cards.Card":{$elemMatch:{Number:18}}}).pretty()` but it gave me `Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Cannot use $elemMatch projection on a nested field.",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"
}`

Comment: Finnaly I tryed `db.teste.aggregate( {$match:{ "Cards.Card.Number":18 }}, {$unwind:"$Cards.Card"}, {$match:{ "Cards.Card.Number":18 }} )` like the answers in the post that @Veeram suggested but it didn't returned anything

Comment: Try `db.teste.find({"Cards.Card.Number":18},{_id:0, "Cards":{$elemMatch:{"Card.Number":18}}}).pretty()` for first version. For second version try `db.teste.aggregate( {$match:{ "Cards.Card.Number":18 }}, {$unwind:"$Cards"}, {$match:{ "Cards.Card.Number":18 }} )`

Comment: It worked, I still have a lot to learn, thanks for your patience!

Comment: well, the second version still gives me an empty result, but at least the first works well

Comment: I changed my database like this: `{"Some":
{"Cards":
              [
                        {"Card":{"_id":{"$oid":"5a46626e150ed3f847f01bac"},"Number":1,"Pag":1}},
                        {"Card":{"_id":{"$oid":"5a466d96150ed3f847f01bad"},"Number":18,"Pag":6}},
                        {"Card":{"_id":{"$oid":"5a466de6150ed3f847f01bae"},"Number":35,"Pag":8}}
              ]
}
}`, just added the "some" in the begin, so I tryed to do: `db.teste.find({"Some.Cards.Card.Number":18},{_id:0, "Cards":{$elemMatch:{"Some.Card.Number":18}}}).pretty()`, but it gives me `[ ]`. It should work

Comment: I tryied `db.teste.find({"Some.Cards.Card.Number":18},{_id:0, "Some.Cards":{$elemMatch:{"Some.Card.Number":18}}}).pretty()` but it gives me `Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Cannot use $elemMatch projection on a nested field.",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"
}`

Comment: Anyone knows how to do?

Comment: Try this... `db.teste.find({"Some.Cards.Card.Number":18},{_id:0, "Some.Cards":{$elemMatch:{"Card.Number":18}}}).pretty()`